# Laravel base64 image Api

Tags: laravel, api, base64

I am developing API in Laravel. I will receive the image in base64 format. How can I convert the base64 to image in Laravel?

```
  public function profile_image_upload(User $user, Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'picture' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
    ], []);
    if ($user->picture !== null)
        Storage::delete($user->picture);

    $res_upload = uploadService::store_image($request->file('picture'), config('upload.user_profile_picture_storage_path'));
    if ($res_upload)
        return $user->update([
            'picture' => $res_upload,
        ]);
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create this helper function

in Helper.php  ref link https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers

```
function base64ImageUpload($path, $file)
    {
        $image = $file; // your base64 encoded

        if (preg_match('/base64/', $file)) {
            $imageInfo = explode(";base64,", $image);
            $imgExt = str_replace('data:image/', '', $imageInfo[0]);

            $image = substr($image, strpos($image, ",") + 1);
            $name = \Str::random(40) . '.' . $imgExt;
            $filePath = $path . '/' . $name;
            \Storage::put($filePath, base64_decode($image));
            return $filePath;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

then whenever u need to upload u can just call this function like

```php
$imageLocation = base64ImageUpload(config('upload.user_profile_picture_storage_path'),$request->picture);
```